# Why is homegroup unable to reconnect after restart/network interuption

Tags: windows-8.1, homegroup

I have just gotten a second laptop to replace my first, and I want to use my old one as my central repository of files and other media. Both are running Windows 8.1, so the easiest way was to set up a Homegroup. So, I created the homegroup on one laptop, joined it on the other, and was able to share my files. However, after I had rebooted my (the joined) laptop, I opened up homegroup, and, although it was listed, it said it was unavailable. I looked on the other, and the same (except referring to the former laptop). Both of them where able to go on the internet, as well as able to ping each other, and access the shares.

If I remove one (usually the joined) laptop from the homegroup, and reconnect it, I can see the shared libraries again, but again, after a reset or other prlonged network outage, and they can't see each other. I don't have a third device to test with to see if I can isolate a specific computer.

There are only Windows Firewalls running on each laptop, and no (for the moment) anti viruses or anything like that. My router is a Virgin Superhub, to which one laptop is wired, the other wireless.

Can somebody please help me find out what is wrong?